# Objects that can be 'pulled apart' without touching each other

Tags: geometry, definition, surfaces, convex-hulls, article-writing

Is the following definition of objects (defined by compact sets) which may be 'pulled apart' without physically touching each other acceptable?

Two compact sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ are said to be separable if there exists positive $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a continuous map $\mathbf{f}:A \times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ where $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},t)=R(t)\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{d}(t) \notin B$ for all $t\in[0,b]$ and $\mathbf{x}\in 
 A$ and $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},t)\notin \text{conv}(B)$ for all $t>b$ and $\mathbf{x}\in A$ ($R$ is a proper rotation matrix whose entries change as a function of $t$ and conv() is the convex hull operat0r).

Because I do not know much about differential geometry, topology, or analysis, edits to this post's title and body that use more 'correct' terminology are appreciated.

If this definition is true, does it also hold for sets in $\mathbb{R}^3
$ that are only bounded?

Comment: By this definition, a (hollow) sphere can be "pulled apart" from an object inside it.

Comment: How?  My current understanding is that the object has to pass through the hollow sphere surface first before being completely outside of the convex hull of the hollow sphere.

Comment: If we treat the hollow sphere as $A$ and the object as $B$, then $A$ is already outside the convex hull of $B$.

Comment: Would requiring two separate maps for $A$ and $B$ alleviate this problem?

Comment: You could probably make something work that way. Another option is to replace the convexity condition with a linear separation: there is a hyperplane $\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x = q$ that separates the final position of $A$ from $B$. (That is, $\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf f(\mathbf x, b) > q$ for all $\mathbf x \in A$, while $\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x < q$ for all $\mathbf x \in B$.)

Comment: That is very helpful; thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141026/discussion-between-fabrizziomuzz-and-misha-lavrov).